# Can TypeScript import both ESM and CJS dependencies?

Tags: typescript, es6-modules, commonjs

I am writing a TypeScript application that uses dependencies installed with NPM:

- some of these dependencies export via CJS
- some of these dependencies export via ESM

Is there a `tsconfig.json` configuration that would let me transparently use all these dependencies?

Comment: I'd set your tsconfig `module` to an esm variant as esm can `import` any commonjs dep. You would run into issues if one of your cjs deps tries to `require` an (transitive) esm dep. See the [compatibility](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#interoperability-with-commonjs) notes.

Comment: What are some of the dependencies you need, so we can try ourselves to make a configuration?

Comment: @caTS I don't understand what difference it would make? NPM is full of CJS and ESM dependencies, any of them would apply here.

Comment: Frankly, I don't know any CJS packages. And I don't know if there is a way to determine that without looking at the source code or trying to use it. It would be convenient for me and others if you could list an example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it can!

For example, this is a fresh ES Module project with an [ESM dependency (chalk)](https://github.com/chalk/chalk) and a [common.js dependency (aes-js)](https://github.com/ricmoo/aes-js):

`package.json`:

```json
{
  "type": "module",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc",
    "start": "yarn build && node dist/index.js"
  },
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/aes-js": "^3.1.1",
    "typescript": "^4.8.4"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "aes-js": "^3.1.2",
    "chalk": "^5.1.2"
  }
}
```

`index.ts`:

```
import chalk from "chalk"
import aesjs from "aes-js"

console.log(chalk.blue(aesjs.utils.utf8.toBytes("this is a string")))
```

tsconfig.json

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2022",
    "module": "es2022",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "outDir": "dist"
  }
}
```

Explanation: [`esModuleInterop`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#esModuleInterop) is your friend. It makes sure that `module.exports =` gets turned into a default export (CommonJS -> ES6) and vice versa, making sure default exports are the same as `module.exports =` (ES6 -> CommonJS)